# Weight bearing glass furniture

Tags: safety, furniture, glass

I've seen some furniture (beds, tables, media units) that are made of wood but sit on glass legs. See this [bed with glass legs](http://www.lago.it/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/knoth-3.jpg).

The glass legs are usually rectangular and appears to be double thickness, fitted vertically.

I was wondered about making something similar and slotting a piece of glass into the bottom of a wooden frame sounds relatively easy

But I would like some advice on the type of glass to use. I presume double thickness is best and toughened glass.

Wondered if anyone had any experience of using glass in this way?

Thanks.

Comment: Apple built an entire store out of glass.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, those are absolutely Tempered Glass, Standard Glass has no lateral stability. And, any glass within 18" of the floor, legally, must be tempered glass regardless of thickness. I've had no breakage problems with glass tables in the past that had taller right angled legs of this rectangular fashion. Glass table tops slide around so you don't stress & break the glass.

But, I don't like that bed setup at all, especially on carpet! Each corner should have 2-pieces to make a corner of glass in order to provide full resistance to both the X & Y axis movements. Sleeping & tossing & turning are one thing, but sex done right is another.

Before I clicked the link, I expected specialty 1-thick wall glass tubes or boxes with metal rods or tubes through them...flanged black or galvanized iron pipe & fittings, painted to whatever you want. Where to get thick walled glass I wouldn't know, but I'd just box-in the legs with small tempered panels siliconed together, being a faux support.

Answer (score 0):

The safest material would be something like a thick plate of polycarbonate. I do not recommend experimenting with normal glass to support anything heavy, especially something that a person would be on.

Comment: If you must use glass, make sure it's tempered safety glass, so you don't stab someone when it fails... Seriously, when you're asking it to carry load there is no such thing as "just glass"; there are many formulations with different characteristics and I know just enough to know that I wouldn't try to guess.

Comment: Now you mention it, I wonder if it actually was glass, as I only saw it on photos.  See this example of a [bed with 'glass' supports](http://www.lago.it/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/knoth-3.jpg).

Comment: Tempered glass is used because it is both very strong and because it crumbles into pebbles when it breaks, instead of scalpel sharp swords. Polycarbonate is extremely strong and a better solution. It's used for anti-shatter safety glasses.

Comment: Polycarbonate scratches very, very easily - so if using that, you will have to take great care to keep it looking at all "glassy" - in normal wear and tear it quickly looks just exactly like scuffed, scratched plastic.

Comment: @Ecnerwal, this appears to be why it's more common for (tacky) furniture to use Acrylic instead of Polycarb when doing clear plastic parts. Looks like you can buy Acrylic couch legs on Amazon. On the note of Tempered glass, that might be a poor substance for the use that peter linked, tempered glass is much weaker on the edges than the face.

Comment: In an environment where there is a high probability you should look into a `mar-resistant` polycarbonate like `Lexan MR` or `Makrolon`.